# PHP PDO bindParam not working with array content

Tags: php, pdo

I have a mechanism that's designed to allow a user to control the *order* in which *products* appear in a *product group*. There's a "`grouplines`" table (**MySQL**) with columns for `group_id`, `product_id`, and `manual_order`.  The first two assign *products* to *groups*, the third determines the *order*.

The `manual_order` values start with **10** and go up in increments of **10**.  So, for example, moving a *product* to be 3rd in the list, is simply a case of changing it's `manual_order` value to 25, and then re-calculating the `manual_order` values.  This is done by obtaining a list of *product ids*, ordered by `manual_order`, and renumbering them in increment.

This piece of code works:

```
$products = array();
$dbh = s3_pdo::get_connection();
$query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT product_id FROM grouplines WHERE group_id=:group_id ORDER BY manual_order');
$query->bindValue(':group_id', $group_id);
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->fetchAll();
$query->closeCursor();
if ($rows) {
    $query = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE grouplines SET manual_order=:manual_order WHERE group_id=:group_id AND product_id=:product_id');
    $query->bindValue(':group_id', $group_id);
    //$query->bindParam(':product_id', $row['product_id']);
    $query->bindParam(':product_id', $product_id);
    $query->bindParam(':manual_order', $i);
    $i = 10;
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $product_id = $row['product_id'];
        $query->execute();
        $i += 10;
    }
}
```

This does not:

```
$products = array();
$dbh = s3_pdo::get_connection();
$query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT product_id FROM grouplines WHERE group_id=:group_id ORDER BY manual_order');
$query->bindValue(':group_id', $group_id);
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->fetchAll();
$query->closeCursor();
if ($rows) {
    $query = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE grouplines SET manual_order=:manual_order WHERE group_id=:group_id AND product_id=:product_id');
    $query->bindValue(':group_id', $group_id);
    $query->bindParam(':product_id', $row['product_id']);
    //$query->bindParam(':product_id', $product_id);
    $query->bindParam(':manual_order', $i);
    $i = 10;
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        //$product_id = $row['product_id'];
        $query->execute();
        $i += 10;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the difference is that the second piece of code binds `$product_id` which is given a value `(from $row['product_id'])` with the *foreach loop*, whereas the first piece of code tries to bind `$row['product_id']` outside of the *loop*... which as far as I'm aware ought to work, but doesn't.

I can only guess at why the second piece of code doesn't work, because I can't find a definite answer. I'd like a definite answer because I'm new to using the `PDO` and don't want to fall foul of this kind of thing as I convert the rest of my system to using the `PDO` instead of the old *mysql_* functions.

Comment: `$query->bindParam(':product_id', $row['product_id']);` won't work, as `$row` it's an array of table rows, ergo array of arrays. If the product_id is the same for all records, then what you need is `$query->bindParam(':product_id', $row[0]['product_id']);`. Also, there is no need for `bindParam`, almost never, so you should be ok with using `bindValue`.

Comment: $row isn't an array of table rows.  $rows (note the s on the end) is the array of table rows.  $row is a single row.

Comment: You weren't exactly clear what you were trying to do. Bind the :product_id in the loop.

Comment: bindValue assesses the value when it's bound.  bindParam assessed when the execute() happens.  So I could use bindValue if I did it within the loop but bindParam should let me do it before the loop.  Note that it works fine with $i.

Comment: PHP doesn't work that way, the sole difference between bindParam and bindValue is that bindParam takes a variable reference so it can modify the variable's value once execute occurs. That's because you can pass variables to MySQL's stored procedures which can alter the value of input parameters. So, tl;dr: bindValue(':product_id', $row['product_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT) in the loop.

Comment: @N.B. I know I can bind it in the loop... but I don't understand why I have to do it with :product_if when I can bind :manual_order before the loop.  What I need to know is why it works for $i and not for $row['product_id']

Comment: Because foreach loop overwrites any possible references that might have existed, since it export every row into a newly created $row variable.

Comment: Shouldn't $query->bindParam(':product_id', $row['product_id']); be $query->bindParam(':product_id', $rows['product_id']); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what your code does:

```
$query->bindParam(':product_id', $row['product_id']);
```

Here you are implicitly creating an array `$row` with one element and pass this **element** as reference to bindParam(). This results in a structure as follows:

```
$row : Array(
           'product_id' => &null
       )
```

Note that `$row` itself is not a reference! As soon as you reach the loop:

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
```

the Array `$row` gets **overwritten**. At this point you are losing the reference in your old $row-Array, the array does not exist anymore. A reference cannot automagically hop over into a different array, just because it has the same key and happens to be assigned to the same variable.

**Long story short: what you are trying to do is not possible.**

Comment: Aha!  That explains it.  I didn't realise that bindParam would actually create the variable (if it wasn't already defined).  Now that you've said it, it makes sense that it does, and of course explains WHY my second piece of code won't work.

Answer (score -1):

1. You are referring to an undefined array index  `$row['product_id']`
2. `$query->bindParam(':product_id', $row['product_id']);`  statement
   fails .
3. use try catch to catch exception

Comment: I haven't tried to catch an exception but don't see why bindParam would fail with $row['product_id'].  It works with $i and $i isn't defined when the bindParam happens.  I thought the whole point with bindParam, as opposed to bindValue, is that the bindParam variable/value is assessed when the execute() is performed... and both $i and $row['product_id'] are defined by the time that happens.

Comment: $row['product_id'] where have tou defined row? thats after bind

Comment: $row is defined by the foreach loop.